# Nuxt3 binding images broken path

Tags: image, vue.js, data-binding, nuxt.js, background-image

I have an array of objects containing image and its respective information that I am iterating through. The path of the image is not rendering correctly.

Here is the sample array this is inside the data() method):

```
samples: 
  [
    { 'title': 'Numero Um', 'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'img': '@/static/img/work/1.jpg' },
    { 'title': 'Numero Dois', 'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'img': '@/static/img/work/2.jpg' },
    { 'title': 'Numero Tres', 'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'img': '@/static/img/work/3.jpg' },
    { 'title': 'Numero Quatro', 'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor, ', 'img': '@/static/img/work/4.jpg' }
  ]
```

The the iteration is:

```
<div class="sampleCard" v-for='(s, index) in samples' :key='index'>
   <img :src="s.img" alt="s.img">
</div>
```

What I get in the browser on the image src is - **@/static/img/work/1.jpg**

Now, if I hard code the @/static/img/work/1.jpg and not bind the src attribute the image displays and in the browser on the image src I get - **/_nuxt/static/img/work/1.jpg**

I'm not sure what Im doing wrong... the image exists and the path is correct. In previous version on Nuxt this worked fine - I'm upgrading an older project manually.

I also tried replacing the "@" with a "~" and still same issue.

ALSO, Im getting the same phenomenon when binding to the style and adding a background image dynamically:

```
<div :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(@/static/img/' + bannerUrl + ')' }">
```

This also used to work fine, but does not with Nuxt3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just realized that I cannot serve dynamic content from the "assets" directory, it must come from a "public" directory. Here is reference to the docs - https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets#example-1